# Non-punctual Boundary

Tags: general-topology, combinatorics, differential-geometry, geometric-topology

In the book of Bill Thurston, Three dimensional geometry and topology, there is an exercise to show torus can be partitioned into 7 countries, each on one piece and has common          (non-punctual) boundary  with every other country. please, can anyone clarify the meaning of non-punctual ?

Comment: Without having the book to hand, I would suggest it might mean that the common boundary is not a point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mark Bennet said, it means every two regions have a nontrivial piece of boundary in common: nontrivial means containing a topological arc, i.e., not being a point. This is a standard detail in [Map coloring problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem), and Thurston's exercise is in the context of map coloring.

Comment: I want to know one more thing : can a particular country have boundary which is union of disjoint arcs (say two disjoint circles) like annulus? I mean will it still be called punctual?

Comment: @Neel "non-punctual" refers to overlaps of boundaries, not boundaries themselves. In any case, union of disjoint arcs is not a point. "Punctual" comes from the word "point".